# Removing item from a list inside for - didn't get ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, list

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.batchFutures.size(); i++) {
    Future<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Location, String>> result = this.batchFutures.get(i);
    Map.Entry<Location, String> entry = null;
    try {
        if (result.isDone()) {
            entry = result.get();
            this.updateStatisticsFor(entry.getValue(), "success");
            this.clearAfterSent(i, entry);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
        this.updateStatisticsFor(entry.getValue(), "fail");
        this.clearAfterSent(i, entry);
    }
}

private void clearAfterSent(
     int i, 
     Map.Entry<SdavcAmazonRequestMsg.DataAffinity, ImmutableList<TelemetryMeta>> entry) {
     this.batchFutures.remove(i);
}
```

I was expecting to get `ConcurrentModificationException` since I'm removing an item from the list in the iteration itself, but I didn't.

I was curious how is it possible and why it didn't happen this time?

Comment: You are not iterating over the list, you're using indexes up to the size of the list. Try `for(Future<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Location, String>> result : this.batchFutures)`, and you'll get it.

Comment: Also you are skipping an element after the removed one (if there is one). When removing element at index `i`,  subsequent elements are shifted to the left, so the one at index `i + 1` gets into index `i`. You are incrementing `i` regardless, so missing that element.

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown from an `Iterator`, and as @ernest_k indicated, you are not using an `Iterator`. Futhermore the exception is thrown on a best-effort basis, there is no guarantee that you will have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd get a `ConcurrentModificationException` is you invalid an iterator used for the loop. Here, you aren't using an iterator, but a simple `int` to count over the list indexes. You won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but you will get the wrong result, as you're modifying the list without accounting for it with the index. For example, assume the first three elements in the list are A, B and C (in indexes 0, 1 and 2 respectively). If A is done, you'll remove it, and B will now be at index `0`. In the next iteration of the loop, you'll progress to check index 1 which now holds C, without ever evaluating B.